# Is there any convention for methods 'converting' an object into another? (toX, fromY)

Tags: java, methods, convention

this is my first question on Stack Overflow; it is more of a curiosity that's interested me, because i've seen both being used.

I have a MapFile class and a Map class. MapFile objects can 'turned into' Map objects. Which one of these is the preferred way? Is there any?

in MapFile.java

```
public Map toMap(){
    Map map;
    // code to make a map
    return map;
}
```

OR

in Map.java

```
public static Map fromMapFile(MapFile f){
    Map map;
    //code to make a map
    return map;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK no there are no conventions about that (voting to close as opinion-based). As a remark, note that the "static" way can make your life a pain when writing unit tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferred way is to create third utility class MapFileToMapAdapter and use it:

```
public class MapFileToMapAdapter {

    private MapFileToMapAdapter() {}

    public static Map toMap(MapFile mapFile) {
        Map map;
        // propagate map
        return map;
    }
}
```

In this case you will have loose coupling in your code: Map and MapFile will not know each other.